# Debugging past a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I want to debug but I get stuck in a loop.

I tried to add breakpoints.

I have tried this but it doesn't work for me. This what I am trying to get past.

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim unique As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = Worksheets("Vlookups")

    For Each Sales In sh.Range("Sales")
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem Sales.Value
    Next Sales

    End Sub
```

The debugger will go to next Sub.

Comment: Is that all of your code?  I ask because is there any reason why you can't simply put a break point directly after the NEXT statement?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I tried that and it did not work. The line after "Next Sales" is blank. then End Sub.

Comment: but if there's nothing after your loop then all you have is End Sub.  Do you want to debug within the loop or after it?  If after it, you have no more code.  If during, you can put if statements or watch points to check for certain data changes or scenarios.

Comment: What happens when you put your break point at end sub?  It should stop, there's no reason why not.

Comment: Just write `Stop` in the line between `Next Sales` and `End Sub` and it will stop there.

Comment: Use the F8 button on the keyboard and it will step through line by line as you press the button. Use the Watch window to watch any variables or objects that are important to you.

Comment: Thanks to all.  I will try the fixes.

Comment: Skin: I have a lot of Subs.  The one I posted works.  I need to get past it to check the others that do not work.

Comment: @Bzltyr Actually we can only help you if you show that code in your question that throws an error or does not work. If you show the working procedure/sub how could we help with that? We can only help on what we see. • Subs are not processed one after the other. They just run if they are either called by any other sub or triggered by any event.

Comment: PEH:  Thanks for the input. I cannot get past the good code because it gets into the loop and I cannot get out.  I do not even know what the bad code is.  That is what I am trying to find out.  If I hit F5 is just crashes.  If I hit F8 is just loops through the code I posted.

Comment: @Bzltyr The problem is that your question is very unclear. Define what "Just crashes" exactly means. What is the result of `MsgBox sh.Range("Sales").Address` if you put that line just right before the loop? What happens if you put `Stop` in the line between `Next Sales` and `End Sub`? You say *"The debugger will go to next Sub."* but `Next Sub` does not exist. • Please [edit] your question and be much more precise.